# Perforce API for Python 2.7

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, perforce

Does anyone know of a Python 2.7 compliant Perforce API build?
On their [FTP](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce) site they have only up to Python 2.6.

It explains in the README how to build it for other versions of Python, however I was running into a lot of issues because I was using VS2010 (I even tried MinGW).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official P4Python build for Python 2.7 is in the works, but you can use the binary build from the Perforce Public Server (public.perforce.com:1666) in //guest/sven_erik_knop/P4Pythonlib/bin/...  or simply follow this link:

http://public.perforce.com:8080/guest/sven_erik_knop/P4Pythonlib/bin/?ac=83

I don't have every combination of P4Python/Python/32-64 bit version built there, but if you require a special build, drop me a line and I see what I can do.

By the way, to build P4Python you need the exact version of Visual Studio that Python was built with, which happens to be Visual Studio 2007.

Sven Erik Knop

Answer (score 0):

I found another link for p4python 64bit download at here:
http://www.filewatcher.com/m/p4python-2.7-x64.exe.7206920-0.html
However, if your python 2.7 is 32-bit, please download the 32bit p4python at here:
https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/utils/python/bin/p4python-2014.1.807760.win32-py2.7.exe?v=1